# Embedding a Markov chain in a Markov process

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let $X_{t\ge 0}$ be a Markov process with values in a metric space $(\mathcal{X},d)$ defined on a probabiltiy space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ and let $(\tau_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of independent a.s. increasing $(\sigma(\{X_s\}_{0\le s\le t}))_{t\ge 0}$-stopping times. Is it true that the process $(Y_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ defined for each $n$ by
$$
Y_n := X_{\tau_n}
$$
is a Markov chain?

More importantly, if we know that there exists some $k\in (0,1)$ such that: for all $t,s\ge 0$ and all $x,y\in \mathcal{X}$ one has
$$
W_1(\operatorname{Law}(X_t|X_0=x),\operatorname{Law}(X_s|X_0=y))\lesssim k^{|t-s|}d(x,y)
$$
then can we conclude that there is some $\tilde{k}\in (0,1)$ for which: for all $n,m\in \mathbb{N}$ and each $x,y\in \mathcal{X}$ we have
$$
W_1(\operatorname{Law}(Y_m|Y_0=x),\operatorname{Law}(Y_n|Y_0=y))
\lesssim k^{|n-m|}d(x,y)
$$
here I've assumed that $\tau_0=0$ $\mathbb{P}$-a.s.

---

**Update:**  The only condition I have is the following: Suppose that for the Laplace transform (MGF) $\psi_n$ of each stopping time $\tau_n$ exists and there is some $\tilde{\kappa}\in (0,1)$ for which: for each $n\in \mathbb{N}_+$ we have the *sub-exponential growth condition*
$$
\phi_n(j\,\kappa) \le \begin{cases}
\tilde{\kappa}^{-n} & \mbox{ if } j=-1\\
\tilde{\kappa}^{n} & \mbox{ if } j=1 \\
\end{cases}
$$
In particular, this condition holds in the case where $\tau_n$ is Poisson with intensity $\lambda_n$ satisfying
$$
\lambda_n \le \min\biggl\{
\frac{\kappa\log(1/\kappa^n)}{1-\kappa}
,
\frac{\kappa\log(\kappa^n)}{\kappa-1}
\biggr\}.
$$
However, this condition looks pretty ugly (to me at-least)...I'm wondering if there is something more elegant.

**Note:** Basically, I want to link some continuous theory with this:
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002212360800493X

Comment: For the first part, presumably you need to assume that $X_t$ has the *strong* Markov property, and then the Markov property for $Y_n$ seems like it should follow immediately.  Is there a difficulty that I'm not seeing?

Comment: But I don't think you can have any result like your last line, since you have no control over how large the stopping times $\tau_n$ might be.  For instance, if $X_t$ is standard Brownian motion, you could let $\tau_1 = 0$, and choose $\tau_2$ so that $X_{\tau_2}$ has any mean-zero finite-variance distribution whatsoever: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skorokhod%27s_embedding_theorem

Comment: @NateEldredge I've clarified, what I meant.  Basically the rate at which the continental law of the process, conditioned on its values at exponential states, should be contracting exponentially.

Comment: @NateEldredge That's what I figured also, I guess one would have to assume that the $\tau_n$ arrive reasonably quickly, w.h.p, but a.s. never all accumulate on an arbitrarily small interval?

Comment: Ok, I guess you mean the second argument of $W_1$ to have $y$ instead of $x$, in both places?

Comment: @NateEldredge I have come up with a working condition.. but I wonder if there's a nicer condition...